# Can singular long models require less than PA?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

Say that a **long model** is an $\mathfrak{A}\models\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}$ has strictly greater cardinality than each of its proper initial segments (in the case $\vert\mathfrak{A}\vert=\aleph_1$ this is "$\omega_1$-like"ness). If $\mathfrak{A}$ is a long model and $\vert\mathfrak{A}\vert$ is regular, then in fact $\mathfrak{A}\models\mathsf{PA}$ since the bounding scheme is trivially satisfied in $\mathfrak{A}$ (see Lemma 2.15 of [Hajek/Pudlak](https://projecteuclid.org/eBooks/perspectives-in-logic/Metamathematics-of-First-Order-Arithmetic/toc/pl/1235421926)). Moreover, by the MacDowell/Specker theorem (see [Kossak, *63 years of the MacDowell-Specker theorem*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.03156.pdf)) the converse holds: if $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal and $\varphi$ is true in every long model of $\mathsf{PA}$ of size $\kappa$, then $\mathsf{PA}\models\varphi$ already. (Given $\mathsf{PA}\not\models\varphi$, let $\mathfrak{B}\models\mathsf{PA}+\neg\varphi$ be countable and iterate MD/S $\kappa$-many times.)

Interestingly, the first observation seems to need regularity:

> Is there a singular cardinal $\kappa$ such that the common theory of long models of size $\kappa$ is strictly weaker than $\mathsf{PA}$?

Comment: I'm not sure about the details yet but I highly suspect that you can use the ideas in the proof of the second Paris-Mills theorem to build a long model of size $\beth_{\omega}$ in which tetration fails to be total. (In particular there will be a countable initial segment whose image under tetration is cofinal in the model.) I think this will still be a model of $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$, but if not you should be able to do it with some hyperoperator.

Comment: @JamesHanson What is the second Paris-Mills theorem? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Suppose that $M$ is countable and $I \subseteq_{\mathrm{end}} M$ is closed under exponentiation. Then for any infinite cardinal $\lambda$, $M$ has an elementary extension $N$ such that the greatest common initial segment of $M$ and $N$ is $I$ and every $N$-definable set containing $I$ has cardinality $\lambda$.

Comment: I think I can write a sub-optimal argument for what I said, but it will take me a bit.

Comment: Oh actually it looks like I don't need to write it up. There's a relevant result mentioned in the Kossak paper you linked. It says Kaye showed that for each $n \geq 1$ and each singular $\kappa$, there is a $\kappa$-like model of $\mathsf{B\Sigma^0_n} + \mathrm{exp}+\neg \mathsf{I\Sigma^0_n}$. That answers your question, right?

Comment: @JamesHanson It's even worse/better than that - a couple sentences later Kossak mentions a beautiful result that's in Ian Haken's thesis (we overlapped at Berkeley), jointly with Slaman, which thoroughly nukes the question. That's what I get for not reading the paper before linking to it! Would you like to put this as an answer, or should I?

Comment: You're probably better equipped to write the answer.

Comment: Hi. Could you please clarify: Does PA stand for Peano Axioms? Or something else?

Comment: @Stef Yes, $\mathsf{PA}$ is first-order Peano arithmetic (occasionally "PA" is used to refer to *Presburger* arithmetic, but that's a rarity in my experience). The standard source on subsystems of $\mathsf{PA}$ is the Hajek/Pudlak book linked in my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The answer to the question is strongly in the positive, since the following theorem of Kaye implies that for *every* singular cardinal $\kappa$, and for any fixed natural number $n$, the common theory of $\kappa$-like models of $\mathrm{I}\Sigma_{n}$ is strictly weaker than $\mathsf{PA}$.

**Theorem.**  *Let $\kappa$ be a singular cardinal,  $n \geq 1$, and let* $M\models \mathrm{B}\Sigma_n + \mathsf{exp} + \lnot\mathrm{I}\Sigma_n$. *Then there is a $\kappa$-like model $K$ that is elementarily equivalent to $M$.*

The above theorem appears as Theorem 2.4 of Kaye's paper *Constructing κ-like models of arithmetic*. **J. London Math. Soc.** (2) 55 (1997), no. 1, pp.1–10. According to Kaye, the paper arose out of a question of Slaman:  Are there $\kappa$-like models of arithmetic for singular $\kappa$ that do not
satisfy $\mathsf{PA}$?

A key ingredient of Kaye's proof is the technology of "doubly indexed indiscernibles" invented by Keisler, who showed that for any consistent extension $T$ of Zermelo set theory, and any given singular cardinal $\kappa$, $T$ has a $\kappa$-like model. This result of Keisler appears in his paper *Models with orderings*, **Logic, methodology and philosophy of science III** (eds. B. van Rootselaar and J. F. Staal; North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1968) 35–62.

It is worth noting that Kaye has another paper related to this topic: *The theory of $\kappa$-like models of arithmetic*. (English summary)
**Special Issue: Models of arithmetic.
Notre Dame J. Formal Logic** 36 (1995), no. 4, pp.547–559.

Comment: Looking at this from an outsider's perspective, so apologies if this is a stupid question: is there hope of a precise description of the theory of $\kappa$-like models for a specific singular cardinal $\kappa$ like, say, $\aleph_\omega$ or the first fixed point of $\gamma\mapsto\aleph_\gamma$ (maybe assuming GCH)? Is it finitely axiomatizable? Is this worth opening another question about?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen As Kaye points out in the paper referenced in the last paragraph of my answer, the work of Keisler on singular-like models makes it clear that $T$ = the theory of $\kappa$-like models for strong limit singular cardinals is recursively axiomatizable (via the scheme dubbed INDISC in Kaye's paper).  The latest work on this subject (that I know of) is that of Haken, referenced in Noah Schweber's answer; which includes a negative answer to a question of Kaye regarding the axiomatization of $T$. I think the finite axiomatizability of $T$ is an open question.

Answer (score 6):

To supplement Ali's answer, I'll also mention the following more recent result of Haken/Slaman: they built a $\kappa$-like model of $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1+\neg B\Sigma_2}$ for $\kappa$ an uncountable singular *strong limit* cardinal. This is Theorem 13 in [Haken's thesis](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/1pj1b1vk).

This leaves open, as far as I know, what can happen at singular cardinals which are not strong limits.

Comment: I changed $\neg B\Sigma_1$ to $\neg B\Sigma_2$, which is what Noah intended to write.

Comment: @AliEnayat Indeed, thank you!